# How do I count back number using int?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
int countfiletodownload = 0;
        bool processStatus = false;
        private void Parseanddownloadfiles()
        {
            downloadhtml(mainurl);
            if (bgw.CancellationPending == false)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, "Parsing Links");
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                doc = hw.Load(path_exe + "\\page.html");
                foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
                {
                    string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
                    if (hrefValue.Contains("US"))
                    {
                        string url = "http://www.datatesting.com" + hrefValue;
                        parsedlinks.Add(url);
                        if (bgw.CancellationPending == true)
                            return;
                    }
                }
                countfiletodownload = parsedlinks.Count;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, "Downloading Files");
                processStatus = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < parsedlinks.Count && bgw.CancellationPending == false; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                        {
                            string filename = parsedlinks[i].Substring(71);
                            client.DownloadFile(parsedlinks[i], filesdirectory + "\\" + filename);
                            string filenametoreport = filename.Substring(1);
                            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, filenametoreport);
                            countfiletodownload 
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        string error = err.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm using `countfiletodownload` and if I will do `countfiletodownload += 1;` it will increment it by one. But if I want to increment it backwards. `countfiletodownload` value is now in this case 13671 and I want to count back each time a file was download. `13671` then `13670,13669...`.

Do I need to make: `countfiletodownload --;` or `countfiletodownload -= 1;`?

Comment: `value--;` is the short form of `value-=1;`. it compiles to the same.

Comment: `increment it backwards` => did you meant `decrement`?

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Wouldn't simply using `foreach(string parsedlink in parsedlinks){ if (bgw.CancellationPending) { break; } try...catch... }` (and then replace `parsedlinks[i]` with `parsedlink`) be enough?

Answer (score 0):

Just start at your file count and go to 0. Then you don't have to worry about keeping a count.

```
Array.Reverse(parsedlinks);

for (int i = parsedlinks.Count - 1; (i >= 0 && !bgw.CancellationPending); i--)
```

You can remove this: countfiletodownload.

Comment: Simple enough, reverse the array. And this will not throw an out of range exception.

Comment: `parsedlinks` is probably not an array (since it has a `Count` property instead of `Length`), if it is a `List<T>` you can use `parsedlinks.Reverse()`.